# Using slice() with or without [end] argument

Tags: javascript, slice

Is there any performance difference using the slice() method with or without the last argument [end]?

Example:

```
var m = ['But', 'Will', 'It', 'Blend', 'Question'];
var r = m.slice(1,3);
```

OR

```
var r = m.slice(2);
```

PS: not the result as it is, but the performance issue only.

Comment: There is no real difference, and you can test that in [**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/slice-and-end-test-ss)

Comment: @adeneo will do. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the implementation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice you will see that if the second argument is not sent then it uses the array length so no, I think they are the same.

```
Array.prototype.slice = function(begin, end) {
  // IE < 9 gets unhappy with an undefined end argument
  end = (typeof end !== 'undefined') ? end : this.length;
  .....................................
});
```

Comment: Well, this may settle it. Thanks, @biancamihai

Comment: That's how you'd write a polyfill in javascript, not the actual implementation. How it's actually implemented in the browsers native code may differ from browser to browser, but there probably won't be much of a performance difference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This function has linear complexity (`O(n)`) in both cases, be it with only one parameter specified, or two. It's the first thing to consider.

The second thing is, in case only one parameter specified, the second one (end of the slice) is being calculated under the hood by default value (`#length`). So you may think of `#slice(4)` call as of `#slice(4, #length)`, and these two will be the same.

Next, when the interpreter takes this call and builds an AST around it, it has to deal with two values, not one. So it may seem like twice as time consuming. But compared to the whole script, this overhead is totally negligible.

So, there's no significant difference in timing between the two. It's purely the question of readability of the code.

Comment: that was really what I meant! Since the O(n) complexity remains, it seems the lack of the last argument becomes a negligible 'constant count' in the complexity indeed. Thank you!